# dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) nginx

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, nginx

The Software up-to-date Option automatically download the upgrade for `nginx`. but While installing it's giving me the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nginx
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/434 kB of archives.
After this operation, 977 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 291344 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nginx (from .../nginx_1.4.7-1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Thanks for using nginx!

Please find the official documentation for nginx here:
* http://nginx.org/en/docs/

Commercial subscriptions for nginx are available on:
* http://nginx.com/products/

----------------------------------------------------------------------
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.4.7-1~precise_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/logrotate.d/nginx', which is also in package nginx-common 1.4.6-1+precise0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.4.7-1~precise_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Actually that file `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` does not exist in this folder.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Run the below commands on your terminal,

```
sudo dpkg -P nginx-common
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If it's shows any dependency problem when uninstalling the above `nginx-common` package, then purge    `nginx-common` package along with it's dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx*
```

Before running the above command, don't forget to check  the dependency packages which are going to be purged along with nginx.

```
sudo apt-get purge -s nginx*
```

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get purge -s nginx*` in your question.

Comment: i had purged the whole nginx and installed it again. actualy it helps me.

Comment: yes, that's what i'm trying to say.

Comment: If you get this on WSL (windows sub-system  ubuntu), restart the bash with Admin rights, and it should fix it.

Comment: I had to add `--force depends` to the purge command, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58964627/1248175)